# Visual Studio 2012 + Business Intelligence Templates

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I got SQL Server 2012 installed on my machine and I have SSDT to create BI projects.

Today i installed Visual Studio 2012; but i cannot create any of BI projects in Visual Studio 2012.  Is there a way I can open BI (SSIS/SSAS/SSRS) projects in VS 2012 or should i have to always go back to SSDT to open them.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft released a patch for VS 2012 that lets you work on SSRS 2012 reports. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [this](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/04/ssdt-installation-confusion/) blog post. Basically, there are two versions of SSDT (even though Microsoft doesn't ever explicitly state this), and depending on how you installed SSDT, you get one or the other version. As a further note, SSDT will only work with BIDS in SQL Server 2012, not 2008R2.

Comment: An editor noted that, "As of April 2013 you will need to install the following components on top of a fresh Visual Studio 2012.2 (Update 2) installation: SSDT for Visual Studio 2012, SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2012, Data-Tier Application Framework (March 2013)".

Answer (score 15):

SSRS development functionality became available for [Visual Studio 2012 in March 2013](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/data-driver/2013/03/bids-templates-added-to-visual-studio-2012.aspx). And Microsoft started to distinguish between SSDT and SSDT-BI (which contains the BI tools). They are complementary installations, and both must be installed for Visual Studio to be happy working with SSRS reports.

The [components needed for SSRS development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) are as follows:

- [Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=274984)
- [Download SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843)
- [Download Data-Tier Application Framework (March 2013)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36842)

Comment: A note about SSDT-BI - It seems that you must choose the same language as WIndows (and not your prefered language or the language of your Visual Studio installation). Otherwise the installation fails with an error: "The SQL Server license agreement cannot be located fort he selected edition"

Answer (score 3):

In addition to this, only SQL Server Data Tools 2010/VS2010 has access to the entire BI suite. This is not yet available for VS2012/SQL Server Data Tools 2012, which only has access to the SQL Database project. Fortunately (or maybe not), both can be installed to the same system without systemic conflict. As to your mental conflict, your mileage may vary.

Comment: It looks like this answer is obsolete as of Tim Lewis's answer from April '13.

Answer (score 1):

It is available now as an additional download at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843