# Can SSDT-BI for VS2012 be used with SQL Server 2014?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2014, ssdt-bi

Can Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 be used with SQL Server 2014 from Visual Studio 2012, or do i need to upgrade to 2013?

It is not clear on the MS pages. We do not want to upgrade to VS2013 unless we really have to, as we have many projects that would have to be upgraded. Can any one clarify and refer me to documented evidence that SQL Server 2014 is supported.

---

Ref:
 - [Visual Studio 2012 + Business Intelligence Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155085/visual-studio-2012-business-intelligence-templates)
 - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36843

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this blog post:

http://erikej.blogspot.com/2015/03/sql-server-data-tools-for-visual-studio.html

the answer is:

NO for SSDT-BI 2012

but

YES for SSDT-BI 2013